# Serverless AWS - Deploy symlink to mounted EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-efs

I would like to put a part of the application on an EFS which I have already mounted.
This part of the application must be editable and must not be read/written so fast, so it is possible to put it on an EFS.
The problem now is that I would like to put a symlink in the deployed code, which points to the mounted folder, so I don't have to change the paths of my application.
But this link is ignored by `serverless deploy`.
I assume that this is because serverless tries to follow the symlink during deployment instead of just deploying it as is.

Does anyone here perhaps have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Could be a limitation of `serverless` because `serverless` does support deployment to places like S3 where symlinks don't exist.

Comment: `serverless` compresses my code to a ZIP file and saves it in an S3 bucket. S3 does not support symlinks, but I think that should be irrelevant because the code (incl. the symlink) would be in the ZIP file.

Comment: I misunderstood and thought it was uploading to EFS. You do need to pass `--symlinks` to `zip` for symlinks to be included as symlinks.

Comment: The problem is that I am not creating the zip file with the `zip` command line tool. `serverless` creates the zip.